# PWA with the @angular/service-worker package

Tags: angular

I am creating a new SPA in Angular that has an offline requirement.

It seems that the @angular/service-worker is the new Angular way of creating a progressive web app. I see a few examples of installing the app and it wires up basic caching but I cannot find any examples of more detailed examples for offline caching.

Has anyone used this package?

Does anyone know of some more detailed examples of how to deal with saving user entered data while offline?

Answer (score 0):

There is not much information out there about that topic. However, there is a google doc about the angular-mobile-toolkit & pwas. It has a section about static and dynamic caching. Unfortunately some sections and links are outdated and it was ridiculously hard to find. So here it is:

https://docs.google.com/document/d/1F0e0ROaZUnTFftmC0XovpREHWHjcXa4CggiFlmifjhw/edit

I tried to use that package, as well, but couldn't get it to work for dynamic caching. So I switched to a custom service worker implementation using googles workbox library. It felt much more stable to me. Plus there is at least some documentation out there. The downside is, you loose some of the cli comfort. I wrote about how I did it. You may want to give it a try:

https://malcoded.com/posts/angular-service-worker

Comment: I ended up using the default implementation for caching the client in the browser. All the other offline functionality I wrote in Angular services using PouchDB as the client side caching. I went down this path after I asked the question in the Angular2 subreddit and one of the Angular team responded saying that is not what service workers are for. Only use them for fire and forget events.